# Django get the sum of all columns for a particular user

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a django model as follows:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    cash=models.DecimalField(max_digits=11,decimal_places=2,default=0)
    balance=models.DecimalField(max_digits=11,decimal_places=2,default=0)
    current_ac=models.DecimalField(max_digits=11,decimal_places=2,default=0)   
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

There can be multiple Orders and multiple users can create orders.

How can I get the sum of all orders for each columns for a particular user, something like

```
ord=Order.objects.filter(added_by.id=1).sum()
```

an SQL equivalent would be something like

```
Select sum(cash), sum (balance), sum(current_ac) from Orders where added_by = 1
```

Comment: What column do you want to sum? `current_ac` or `cash`?

Comment: all of them. Suppose there are 2 orders order 1 and 2 with cash 3 and 5, balance 1 and 2 and current ac 3 and 4. I want the output to be an Order object with cash 8, balance 3 and current ac 7 as values.

Comment: see edited answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can aggregate, for example the sum of the `current_ac` with:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from django.db.models import Sum

ord=Order.objects.filter(added_by_id=1).aggregate(
    total=Sum('current_ac')
)['total'] or Decimal()
```

or if you want  to sum up the items for `cash`, `balance` and `current_ac`, you can work with:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from django.db.models import Sum

ord=Order.objects.filter(added_by_id=1).aggregate(
    total_cash=Sum('current_ac'),
    total_balance=Sum('balance'),
    total_ac=Sum('current_ac')
)
```

here `ord` will be a dictionary that contains the corresponding values, for example:

```
{
  'total_cash': Decimal('14.25'),
  'total_balance': Decimal('13.02'),
  'total_ac': Decimal('17.89')
}
```

or if you want to count the number of `Orders`, then we can work with:

```
from decimal import Decimal

ord=Order.objects.filter(added_by_id=1).count()
```

If you want to do that *per* `User`, it is more efficient to work with [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate).

Answer (score 2):

If I get you correctly. You want to count the number of records, right? if that's the case. You can use filter and count. like in the example below:

```
numberOfRecords = Orders.filter(added_by=user_id).count
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this
from django.db.models import Sum

```
total=Order.objects.filter(added_by_id=1).aggregate(
    total=Sum('current_ac')
)['total'] or 0
```