# Django ORM equivalent of SQL Sum

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I have a django model as follows:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    cash=models.DecimalField(max_digits=11,decimal_places=2,default=0)
    balance=models.DecimalField(max_digits=11,decimal_places=2,default=0)
    current_ac=models.DecimalField(max_digits=11,decimal_places=2,default=0)   
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

There can be multiple Orders and multiple users can create orders.

How can I get the sum of all orders for each columns for a particular user using Django queries, an SQL equivalent would be something like

```
Select sum(cash), sum (balance), sum(current_ac) from Orders where added_by = 1
```

Comment: I believe this is answered in your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67956302/django-get-the-sum-of-all-columns-for-a-particular-user), or atleast you ask the same thing there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django get the sum of all columns for a particular user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67956302/django-get-the-sum-of-all-columns-for-a-particular-user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your expected result from the code below

```py
from django.db.models import Sum
result = Order.objects.filter(added_by_id=1).aggregate(total_cash=Sum('cash'), total_balance =Sum('balance'), total_current_ac=Sum('current_ac'))
```

and it will give you a dictionary like this:

```
{'total_cash': Decimal('110.00'), 'total_balance': Decimal('110.00'), 'total_current_ac': Decimal('110.00')}
```